# Binding progressbar visibility mvvm not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

sorry for my bad english :x

I use MVVM Light toolkit on my project and i try to collapsed and restored a progressbar but i have used a lot of snippet and browse a lot of forums around this subject and i can not solve my problem.

My Home.xaml

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="16" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisibility}"/>
```

My HomeViewModel :

```
    private System.Windows.Visibility progressBarVisibility;

    public System.Windows.Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
    {
        get { return progressBarVisibility; }
        set
        {
            progressBarVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisibility");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the HomeViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        this.ContentStatutBar = "Recherche de mises à jour en cours";
        this.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.DownButtonVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        this.flag = false;

        this.fakeButtonAction = new RelayCommand(() => this.update());
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if (!this.flag)
        {
            this.flag = true;

            this.ContentStatutBar = "Une mise à jour en attente";
            this.progressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.DownButtonVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            this.flag = false;

            this.ContentStatutBar = "Aucune mises à jour";
            this.progressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.DownButtonVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        this.ContentStatutBar = this.DownButtonVisibility.ToString();
    }
```

When i use my update method in my Home.xaml.cs it's work (not binding --> (progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible)) but when i try to use this by binding in my VM it's don't work :[

Can you help me please ?

Best Regards ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the field, update the property in your update method

```
      this.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, i am ashamed --'